# SQL Syntax and a missing value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hi I have three tables as the following

[image]

Simply I want to get a list of courses that a student passed (mark > 60).

I used this SQL syntax

```
string queryString = "select c.coursename from Courses c, RegisteredIn R where R.CourseId=c.id and R.StudentId=StudentId and R.mark > 60 ";
```

and I did this to print out the results

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();

                result = string.Empty;
                int counter = 1;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _coursename = reader[0].ToString();
                    result += string.Format("{1} - Course Name : {0} </br>  ",
                        _coursename,
                        counter);
                    counter++;
                }
         
           
               Response.Write(result);
              
                reader.Close();
```

the results showing are

```
1 - Course Name : ADE 
2 - Course Name : LMW 
3 - Course Name : PBC
```

which are correct but the first value is missing the results should be

```
1 - Course Name : AWM 
2 - Course Name : ADE 
3 - Course Name : LMW 
4 - Course Name : PBC
```

I can't figure it out why it keeps skipping the first result

kindly advise ..

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get rid of your first call to `Read`:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();  // <-- Remove this
```

What you have in your `while` loop is already sufficient:

```
while (reader.Read()) { ... }
```

(And a somewhat counter-intuitive sidenote:  the result set starts out at a position *before* the first record, so the first call to `Read` actually places the cursor at the first row)

Answer (score 1):

After you call the `command.ExecuteReader()` function, the next statement is `reader.Read();` which reads the first result of the query.

You don't do anything with that result.  Then the `while` loop  executes the `reader.Read()` as it's condition expression, which get the 2nd and subsequent results. Those results are output by the code, but the first result is not used.

If you just removed that first `reader.Read()` method call and let the while loop do all the `Read` method calls, I think you'll get the expected result